# Why I get 0 as a value in my array elements?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm encountering a problem with the code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
{
    intarray = new int[nr];
    intarray[i] = generateRandom(4);
    Console.WriteLine(intarray[i]+"Test1 "+i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < intarray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(intarray[i]+"Test2 "+i);
}

//nr = 3
```

Some outputs : http://prntscr.com/5d8msx http://prntscr.com/5d8nkm ... **.My problem that first 2 (intarray[0] and intarray[1]) are always 0**, why are they always 0 because they aren't supposed to. **intarray is initialiazed outside the function.** Btw the generateRandom is this

```
Random r = new Random();
static int generateRandom(int max)
{
    int randnum = r.Next(0, max);
    return randnum;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new array in the for-loop each time:

```
intarray = new int[nr];
```

This part should be outside the loop. 
Since `int` is a `value-type`, all values of the array are initialized with its `default value (0)`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize you array outside loop.

```
   var intarray = new int[nr];
   for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {

        intarray[i] = generateRandom(4);
        Console.WriteLine(intarray[i]+"Test1 "+i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < intarray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(intarray[i]+"Test2 "+i);
    }
```

What you are doing now is create new array every time. and `int` init by 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is wrong.

Every iteration in your first `for` loop, you are creating a new *array reference.* Since your array type is `int`, all elements of your array fills with `0` by default.

Since in [`Random.Next(int, int)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx), minimum values is inclusive, it *might* generate `0` as a result.

For example;

In your first iteration `i` is `0` and you create an array referance called `intarray`  with `new int[3]` and you assing `intarray[0]` some random number (which is from `0` to `3`) but the other elements in your array (`intarray[1]` and `intarray[2]`) are filled with `0` which is default value for an `int`.

At last iteration; your `nr` value is `3` and your `i` is `2`. That means you fill your `intarray[2]` with a random number from `0` to `3`, but since you didn't assing any value your `intarray[0]` and `intarray[1]` elements, they still keep `0` value by default.

As a solution, you should initialize your array outside of your for loop, like;

```
intarray = new int[nr];
for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
{
    intarray[i] = generateRandom(4);
    Console.WriteLine(intarray[i] + "Test1 " + i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < intarray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(intarray[i] + "Test2 " + i);
}
```